# How do I make a full screen background change on refresh?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, server-side

I want to make the background image of [this web page](http://www.torenhann.com/) alternate pictures on refresh.

How could I accomplish this?

[Offliberty](http://www.offliberty.com) does this. I've looked at the source code but can't quite figure it out. I found out that it's done with server side scripting and my host does support that, and that a script called sizzle is powering the Offliberty website but I'm just so confused when I look at the code.

Comment: This can be done using jQuery, but would be easiest using a server-side script. Can you use anything on server side - PHP, ASP.NET, Perl, Python...?

Answer (score 8):

You could easily do this on the client side as well if you want. Create multiple classes in your css:

```
backgr0 { background-image: url('images/somepic.jpg'); }
backgr1 { background-image: url('images/somepic.jpg'); }
backgr2 { background-image: url('images/somepic.jpg'); }
backgr3 { background-image: url('images/somepic.jpg'); }
backgr4 { background-image: url('images/somepic.jpg'); }
```

Then in your jQuery ready function:

```
$(function(){
   var backnum = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
   $('body').addClass("backgr" + backnum);
});
```

Replace body with an #id of a div if needed.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to do this on the server side, it seems to me you're using PHP, so I give you an example in that language. The background-image changes only on reload, so logically the difference should be in the HTML the client receives from the server.

You should use the same CSS classes that **@DarthJDG** has provided for you. The only difference is that you will attach the classes on the server, and not on the client side.

```
$number_of_classes=7; //the number of background images you have
$which_one=rand(0, $number_of_classes-1); //let's choose a class

printf('<body class="backgr%s">', $which_one); //put this wherever you are printing body
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I kiinda understand php more than jquery which is basically nothing at all but where exaclty do I put the top two lines?

Comment: @Toren Wherever you would output your `body` tag. For example if you have something like `echo '<body>';` replace it with my code.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have no idea why I didn't just try that. :)

Comment: @Toren If you found a solution in any of the answers here, be sure to mark it as an answer by clicking on the tickmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to find out if something is done with JavaScript or server-side code, the first thing you can do is turn off JavaScript entirely, reload the page a few times, and see what happens.

Unfortunately, Offliberty has everything invisible by default, so it just looks like a blank screen when there's no JS. However, the content is all still *there*, so it'll still work.

Those big background images are being applied to the `#wrapper` div, and when I refreshed - even with JS turned off - that background image was changing.

So it looks like they're using server-side stuff to do it.

(Also, for what it's worth, [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) is a JavaScript library that makes selecting elements much easier. It doesn't change anything for the user, it just makes development a little simpler.)

Answer (score -1):

`<div id=wrapper class=wrapper4>` there are 20 or so background options found in the css. If you dont want to use php asp or severside code. you can write a javascript for this

```
document.write ( '<div id=wrapper class=wrapper' + Math.floor(Math.random()*21) + '>');
```